# VBA copy paste equally in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to copy-paste from drop down list, but it is pasting all tables in column. I would like to paste in two columns equally spaced to print easily.

```
Sub Cha()

Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long

Set dvCell = Worksheets("Summary-Chentir").Range("Q4")
Set inputRange = Worksheets("Names").Range("I3:I20")

i = 1
inc = 0

For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value 
    Sheets("Summary-Chentir").Select
    Range("L2:R21").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Paste").Select
    Cells(i + 1 + inc, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
    Operation:=xlNone, 
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    i = i + 1
    inc = inc + 22
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the .Select/Selection. first and foremost.  It detracts from the goal and readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
Sub Cha()
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set dvCell = Worksheets("Summary-Chentir").Range("Q4")
    Set inputRange = Worksheets("Names").Range("I3:I20")
    i = 1
    inc = 0
    For Each c In inputRange
        dvCell = c.Value 
        Sheets("Summary-Chentir").Range("L2:R21").Copy
        Sheets("Paste").Cells(i + 1 + inc, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        i = i + 1
        inc = inc + 22
    Next c
End Sub
```

---

Will use a For loop, rather than For Each loop because of how I will recommend to do this.

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, dvCell As Range
Set dvCell = Worksheets("Summary-Chentir").Range("Q4")
For i = 3 to 20
    dvCell = Sheets("Names").Cells(i,"I").Value
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        j = 2
    Else
        j = 1
    End If
    Sheets("Summary-Chentir").Range("L2:R21").Copy
    Sheets("Paste").Cells(i + 1 + inc, j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then inc = inc + 22
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer but I cant split the range it is one table linked with drop down list. So,  I have 50 table in column I would like to split in two columns with the same drop down order

Comment: @arehman_91 Can you elaborate on "linked wiht a drop-down list"?  I'll be honest that I'm a bit confused without seeing the data; can you upload a SS (regarding the 50 tables)?

Comment: From data validation I have used drop down list which is working as a variable, on the basis of the this list I have table if any variable changes through drop down list values in the table changes due to sumifs and other formula linked with drop down.

Comment: So, I wanted to paste this whole table with the same order defined in drop down list, equally in two columns. My current VBA only paste in one column, I would wanted that to paste like first table in first column, second table to be pasted in second column, third table right beneath the first table which is first column but after some rows to make sure it would not paste over first table, fourth right beneath the second table and so on .....

Comment: @arehman_91 I think i'm following now... give me a sec to mock-up.

Comment: @arehman_91 Look now; gave you another variable for your column and it determins if i is divisible by 2.